# DocumentDB Data migration Tool, can't migrate from db to db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I'm using DocumentDB Data Migration Tool to migrate a documentDB db to a newly created documentDB db. The connectionStrings *verify* say it is ok.
It doesn't work (no data transferred (=0) but not failure written in the log file (Failed = 0).

Here is what is done :
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried many things such as :

1. migrate / transfer a collection to a json file
2. migrate to partitionned / non partitionned documentdb db
3. for the target indexing policy I've taken the source indexing policy (json got from azure, documentdb db collection settings).
4. ...

Actually nothing's working, but I have no error logs, maybe a problem of documentdb version ?

Thanx in advance for your help.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Well, actually as there is no logs generated, it is difficult to know where the failure comes from. Generally Azure issues are from professional server - or ..., so you may put off-topic almost all Azure issues ..., and I haven't found any solution to this pb on differents forums...

Comment: I just quoted the close vote reason of SO. So, yeah, a lot of the [tag:azure] questions on here are off-topic for a programming website. That doesn't make this a programming question, does it? I've actually initiated the closing of all of the 1657 [tag:godaddy] questions once, so I hardly believe in the "someone posted a question on the same topic before, so this has to be on-topic" argument :). Still, I believe you'd be better off elsewhere than here; it's not that I want to hinder you, I just think you'll get better help somewhere else, and that this website needs to be programming only.

Comment: Note that we didn't just close all [tag:godaddy] questions – we retagged the ones that had actual programming questions, and we closed the ones that weren't about programming.

Comment: This is by no means a question on infrastructure. Is about a specific tool to extract data from a database that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

After debugging the solution from the [tool's repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool) I figure the tools fail silently if you mistyped the database's name like I did.

DocumentDBClient just returns an empty async enumerator.

`var database = await TryGetDatabase(databaseName, cancellation);
            if (database == null)
                return EmptyAsyncEnumerator<IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>>.Instance;`

Comment: great find - also database and collection names are CaSe SeNsItIvE

Answer (score 0):

I can import from an Azure Cosmos DB DocumentDB API collection using [DocumentDB Data Migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data).

[image]

Besides, based on my test, if the name of the **collection** that we specify for **Source DocumentDB** is not existing, no data will be transferred and no error logs is written.

[image]

***Import result***

[image]

Please make sure the source collection that you specified is existing. And if possible, you can try to create a new collection and import data from this  new collection, and check if data can be transferred.

Comment: I think most of my entry parameters are correct, I verify connectionStrings ==> reply ok... I notice something strange, in use cases, we can import many collections in the same time, the example given is the list of collection names separated by '|', when I try this, it tries to import a collection which name is the list of collection names, it doesn't try to import all the collections...

Comment: I do a test and find that if **Target DocumentDB** is **partitioned**, importing data from multiple collections can work fine, but if import data from multiple collections to a single-partition collection, only the first collection's data of collection list is imported.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same problem and after some investigation found that internal document structure was changed. Therefor after migration with with tool documents are present but couldn't be found with data explorer (but with query explorer using select * they are visible)

I've migrated collection through mongo api using [Mongichef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-mongochef)

Answer (score -1):

@fguigui:  To help troubleshoot this, could you please re-rerun the same data migration operation using the command line option? Just launch dt.exe from the same folder as Data Migration Tool for syntax required. Then after you launch it with required parameters, please paste the output here and I'll take a look what's broken.

Comment: thanx alekseys, for the moment I see this error message with dt.exe : Critical error: Documents collection name is required though I put these parameters : /s.Collection:Account and  t.Collection:Account (with or without double quote), I continue testing ...